# Group related elements in array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array in the following format:

```
[8106] => Array (
    [id1] => 210470
    [id2] => 216298
)

[8107] => Array (
    [id1] => 210470
    [id2] => 187145
)

[8108] => Array (
    [id1] => 187145
    [id2] => 216298
)

[8109] => Array (
    [id1] => 187145
    [id2] => 210470
)

[8110] => Array (
    [id1] => 266533
    [id2] => 249612
)
[8111] => Array (
    [id1] => 249612
    [id2] => 266533
)
```

I need to get it into the following format:

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => 266533
    [1] => 249612
)
[1] => Array (
    [0] => 187145
    [1] => 210470
    [2] => 216298
)
```

Basically, I need to extract all the ids, keep the relationships, but group them all together.  I have a function to do this, but it takes forever (I am up to 30+ minutes on the number of rows I have to run through).  Keys and order are unimportant.  The relationship is all that is important.  I am looking for a faster method.  The function(s) I am using are below:

```
function getMatchingIDs($filteredArray)
{
    $result = array();

    $resultCount = 0;
    foreach ($filteredArray as $details) {
        $imaId1 = inMultiArray($details['id1'], $result);
        $imaId2 = inMultiArray($details['id2'], $result);

        if ($imaId1 === false && $imaId2 === false) {
            $result[$resultCount++] = array(
                $details['id1'],
                $details['id2'],
            );
        } elseif (is_numeric($imaId1) === true && $imaId2 === false) {
            $result[$imaId1][] = $details['id2'];
        } elseif ($imaId1 === false && is_numeric($imaId2) === true) {
            $result[$imaId2][] = $details['id1'];
        } elseif ($imaId2 != $imaId1) {
            $result[$imaId1] = array_merge($result[$imaId1], $result[$imaId2]);
            unset($result[$imaId2]);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

function inMultiArray($elem, $array)
{
    if (is_array($array) === true) {
        // if the variable $elem is in the variable $array return true
        if (is_array($array) === true && in_array($elem, $array) === true) {
            return true;
        }

        // if $elem isn't in $array, then check foreach element
        foreach ($array as $key => $arrayElement) {
            // if $arrayElement is an array call the inMultiArray function to this element
            // if inMultiArray returns true, than return is in array, else check next element
            if (is_array($arrayElement) === true) {
                $value = inMultiArray($elem, $arrayElement);
                if ($value === true) {
                    return $key;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // if isn't in array return false
    return false;
}

$filtered = getMatchingIDs($unfiltered);
```

**EDIT:** The original array describes relations between pairs of ids (not shown in the array). The desired output is that the relations are further defined. If you look in the original array, elements 8106-8109 are simply paired combinations of three ids. I need those three grouped together. Elements 8110 and 8111 are a distinct pair, just in a different order.

Comment: Can you describe how the desired output should be in words?

Comment: I added the requested information to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @kingzero Even after your description it is still not clear to me what the logic is for grouping these values. For example, how do you know that elements 8106-8109 are related to each other and why do the id's in these elements map to the index position of 1 in the result array?  You also mention number or "rows"  Does that imply this data is coming from a database?  If so, have you tried to modify your DB query to get the data structure you desire?

Comment: The ids represent similar names in a database. The first array is the result of pulling the data out of the database on MySQL's soundex and then running it through PHP's levenshtein function. The levenshtein() function determines how closely related a pair is which produces the first array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally ended up doing was in essence creating an index array.  This array held all the positions of each value in the primary array.

So the following array

```
[0] => Array (
    [0] => 266533
    [1] => 249612
)
[1] => Array (
    [0] => 187145
    [1] => 210470
    [2] => 216298
)
```

has an index of:

```
[187145] => 1
[210470] => 1
[216298] => 1
[249612] => 0
[266533] => 0
```

So instead of looking for the value in the primary multidimensional array, I check to see if it exists in the index array and process the data based on that.  The results are that it now runs the entire process in <5 seconds instead of > 1 hour.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
  $newArray[0][] = $v['id1'];
  $newArray[1][] = $v['id2'];
}
```

Comment: That would work except for the instance mentioned in the edit.